# How do I hide a category with no existing records? CakePhP

Tags: html, cakephp

I've made a foreach within a foreach that creates a category div with the FAQ questions ascociated with it. Now I want to hide existing categories that don't have any related FAQ's yet. How do I do this?

View:

```
<?php foreach($faqtypetexts as $faqtypetext):?>
  <div class="faqcatdiv">
    <h1><?php echo $faqtypetext['Faqtypetext']['faqtypetext_name']; ?></h1>
    <?php foreach($faqtexts as $faqtext):?>
      <?php if($faqtypetext['Faqtype']['faqtype_id'] == $faqtext['Faq']['faq_rel_faqtype']): ?>
        <section class="faq-section">
          <input type="checkbox" id="q1">
          <label for="q1"><?php echo $faqtext['Faqtext']['faqtext_question']; ?></label>           
          <p>????</p>
          <p><?php echo $faqtext['Faqtext']['faqtext_awnser']; ?></p>   
        </section>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller function:

```
public function faq() {

  // load the website base-layout
  $this->layout = 'website';

  // load relevant models
  $this->loadModel('Faqtext');
  $this->loadModel('Faqtypetext');

  // haal relevante snippets op
  $activelanguage = 2;
  $faqtexts = $this->Faqtext->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Faq.faq_online' => '1', 'Language.language_id' => '2')));
  $faqtypetexts = $this->Faqtypetext->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Language.language_id' => '2')));

  // send snippets to screen
  $this->set('faqtexts', $this->Faqtext->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Faq.faq_online' => '1', 'Language.language_id' => '2'))));
  $this->set('faqtypetexts', $this->Faqtypetext->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Language.language_id' => '2'))));

  // haal relevante contentitems op

  // send content to screen


  // haal nieuws uit de database

  // send to screen

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work I had to compact the large array I had to an array with only the information I needed. I did this with an classicExtract

```
//get all FAQs
$faqs = $this -> Faq -> find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
            'Faq.faq_online' => 1               
        )
));
$this->set('faqs', $faqs);
debug($faqs);

//get all faqtexts
$faqtypetexts = $this -> Faqtypetext -> find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Faqtypetext.faqtypetext_rel_language' => $activelanguage
    ),  
    'contain' => false
));
$this->set('faqtypetexts', $faqtypetexts);


//make list more compact
$categories = Set::classicExtract($faqtypetexts, '{n}.Faqtypetext.faqtypetext_rel_faqtype');
$this->set('categories', $categories);
```

As for the view I made a variable that is empty when the loop through the categories start. If the variable is empty it is allowed to echo the category name, when it loops again and the variable is filled with the same value as previous it is not allowed to echo the category name. Once the value of category name changes it is allowed to echo the category name.

```
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - Repeatable FAQ Div - - - - - - - - - - -->

<?php $lastcategory = ''; ?>  

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - Category Title - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <?php foreach ($faqs as $faq): 

        $faqtypekey = $faq['Faq']['faq_rel_faqtype'];      

        //$categories is result from classicExtract
        $categoryPosition= array_search($faqtypekey, $categories); 

        $categoryRecord = $faqtypetexts[$categoryPosition]; 

        $actualcategory = $categoryRecord['Faqtypetext']['faqtypetext_name']; ?>

        <?php if($actualcategory != $lastcategory){ ?>
            <center>
                <table border="0" width="85%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <img src="<?php echo FULL_BASE_URL . $this->Html->webroot . 'pics/' . $pixelimage['Image']['image_img']; ?>" height="20" width="1">
            <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <div class="categorytitle"><?php echo $actualcategory; ?></div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>                               
        <?php } ?>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - FAQ Content - - - - - - - - - - -->

                    <?php $faqtexts = $faq['Faqtext']; ?>

                    <?php foreach ($faqtexts as $faqtext):

                        if ($faqtext['faqtext_rel_language'] == 2) { ?> 

                            <center>
                                <table border="0" width="85%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                            <section class="faq-section" style="margin: 20px 0 0 5px; position:relative;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="q1">
                                                    <h4 style="color:#925050;" for="q1"><b><span style="font-weight: lighter;">Q: </span>
                                                    <?php echo $faqtext['faqtext_question']; ?></b></h4>
                                                    <?php echo $faqtext['faqtext_awnser']; ?>                           
                                            </section>
                                        </td>               
                                    </tr>

                        <?php } ?>

                                </table>
                            </center>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - End of file - - - - - - - - - - -->

                    <?php endforeach;

                $lastcategory = $actualcategory;


    endforeach; ?>
```

Sorry the awnser post took so long, but I had to rework all divs into tables.

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

- [Use the counter cache](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html) - best solution
- [Use count() on the results](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) - makes only sens if all results of a category are fetched
- [Do a count sub-query](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries) - worst because of performance

Oh, and please work on your code formatting style, this is *horrible* to read.

Comment: Alright if I use counter cache how do I mix it in with my find statement? or wherever it has to go.

Comment: Have you read the linked page? It describes how it works in the first paragraph, please read it. You need to add a field to the table, the behaviour updates the count automatically on save / delete and keeps it up to date.

Comment: I think I actually have to change my find statement, and put the restriction in my view because counter cache looks way too far fetched.

Comment: Hu!? It's dead simple and efficient. Add field, add behavior. Done. It's a one line code change if you follow the conventions.